# How to invalidate Http session from all devices where user was login?

Tags: java, rest, session, session-variables, session-cookies

I have to use httpSession concept for user login state management. I am storing userID as attribute in http session at the time of login and we have to use that userid for subsequent request. is this the right way of storing user login state?.

also my other question is as we are creating httpsession object using request send from particular browser and if i am login from another browser then another session is created and if i want to change the password for that user i should able to invalidate all the sessions associated with that particular user from another browsers like when we are changing password for facebook it asks us to log out from all other devices. so How can i do this?

Comment: Can you explain it some more ? @Rahul

Comment: I have edited the question

Comment: Generate auth token and store DB & send to store in session that can be used to validate the UserId Session Status .So if User changes the password update authtoken in DB so if other session is open it will be invalidated.